# ExtJs How to bind grid record in ViewModel fields?

Tags: extjs, mvvm, data-binding, grid, viewmodel

I have one Form panel with one textfield and a grid. Now, I want to take `userinput` and get the value Through ViewModel as `json` to send it to server.

Problem here is, I am able to bind textfield so I am getting textfield value as one parameter in view model but how can I get selected grid row data as second parameter in `viewMolde.getData()`.

For Example:

> Model:

```
 Ext.define('UserModel', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [{
         name: "name",
         type: "string"
     }, {
         name: "gridRecord",
         type: "auto"
     }]
 });
```

---

> View Model :

```
Ext.define('QAVM', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.QAVM',
    model: 'UserModel'
});
```

---

> View :

```
 Ext.define('View', {
     extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
     xtype: 'app-test',
     viewModel: 'QAVM',
     items: [{
         xtype: 'textfield',
         fieldLabel: 'TestInt',
         bind: '{name}' /**ABLE TO BIND and GETTING VALUE In viewModel.getData()*/
     }, {
         xtype: 'grid',
         title: 'Simpsons',
         formBind: true,
         store: 'storeName',
         bind: {
             selection: 'gridSelectedRecord'
         }, //HOW TO BIND GRID SELECTED RECORD TO MODEL'S SECOND FIELD "gridRecord"
         columns: [{
             text: 'Address-1',
             dataIndex: 'addr'
         }, {
             text: 'Pincode',
             dataIndex: 'pincode',
             flex: 1
         }]
     }]
 });
```

---

Comment: It's a wonder that you get the `name field` in this way. A viewmodel doesn't have a `model property` (for a reason) and you should remove it. Look at the possible config options: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.ViewModel

Answer (score 5):

First of all I want to say that imo your approach is wrong. You don't want to send your data to the server by getting your data from your `viewmodel`. You want to send your record to the server through a `proxy` on your `model` or `store`. The data from your `viewmodel` should only be used to bind to your `view`. The `store` and the `models` are your server data. But a `store` can be bind (and filtered) through a `viewmodel` to your `view`.

`Model-View-ViewModel` is a pattern where the `model` is for your data (and migration through `proxy`), the `view` to represent your data and the `viewmodel` to glue your `model` and your `view` together.

> Now my answer.

You can do that using `formulas` on your `viewmodel`. You can then bind deep the current selection of the grid to your form.

> ViewModel:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.group.GroupsModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.group-groups',

    stores: {
        allgroups: {
            source: 'Groups',
            sorters: {
                property: 'name',
                direction: 'ASC'
            }
        }
    },
    data: {
        title: 'Groups'
    },
    formulas: {
        currentRecord: {
            // We need to bind deep to be notified on each model change
            bind: {
                bindTo: '{groupGrid.selection}', //--> reference configurated on the grid view (reference: groupGrid)
                deep: true
            },
            get: function(record) {
                return record;
            },
            set: function(record) {
                if (!record.isModel) {
                    record = this.get('records').getById(record);
                }
                this.set('currentRecord', record);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

> View:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.group.Groups', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'groups',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.group.GroupsController',
        'MyApp.view.group.GroupsModel',
        'Ext.grid.column.Boolean',
        'Ext.form.field.Checkbox',
        'Ext.form.field.TextArea',
        'Ext.form.field.Text'
    ],

    controller: "group-groups",
    viewModel: {
        type: "group-groups"
    },

    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        pack: 'start',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    style: {
        backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        reference: 'groupGrid', //--> used in the viewmodel
        flex: 1,
        bind: {
            title: '{title}',
            store: '{allgroups}'
        },
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Description',
            dataIndex: 'description',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            xtype: 'booleancolumn',
            text: 'Active',
            trueText: 'Yes',
            falseText: 'No',
            dataIndex: 'isActive'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'form',
        title: 'Details',
        bodyPadding: 15,
        minWidth: 300,
        split: true,
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            anchor: '100%',
            allowBlank: false,
            enforceMaxLength: true
        },
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            bind: '{currentRecord.name}' //--> get current selected record from viewmodel
        }, {
            xtype: 'textarea',
            fieldLabel: 'Description',
            bind: '{currentRecord.description}',
            height: 120
        }, {
            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Active',
            bind: '{currentRecord.isActive}'
        }]
    }]
});
```

---

After editing a `model` or adding models to your `store` save/sync your `store` or save your `model`.

Comment: Thank you very much Tarabass for explaining in detail.You example is quite clear... But requirement is something different. I want to pick data on form submit button something like this...                                                 { id:1009 , name : "Nishant ", contacts:[{ phone:91XX , email:"nish@xyz.com"}, { phone:91XX , email:"nirav@abc.com"},{ phone:88XX , email:"alok@nmp.com"}] }

Comment: So in one single form I need two textfield for id and name & array of contacts I am supposed to pick from grid selections. And one save button which will pick inputs from textfields and grid selection and send it to server.

Comment: For that you need associated models. A `user model` with a hasMany relation to a `contact model`. Then you can save/sync the store related to the loaded record (user model) of the form or save the user model (loaded record in form). http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-hasMany http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field-cfg-reference http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.schema.Association

Comment: I do not understand what does the formula add here. You could do this directly:
{
  fieldLabel: 'Name',
  bind: '{groupGrid.selection.name}'
},

Answer (score 1):

Tested on extjs 6.

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    bind: {
        store: '{gridStore}',
        selection: '{selectedRow}' //--> used in the viewmodel
    }
}
```